# Azure Powershell fails with vague error: One or more errors occurred

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet, vhd

I am trying to download a Azure vhd to local disk. The process starts, creates the file, reports progress then exits with the below message.

```
Save-AzureVhd -Source $sourceVHD -LocalFilePath $destinationVHD -NumberOfThreads 5 -verbose
Elapsed time for download: 00:00:37
Save-AzureVhd : One or more errors occurred.
At line:4 char:1
+ Save-AzureVhd -Source $sourceVHD -LocalFilePath $destinationVHD -NumberOfThreads ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Save-AzureVhd], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.AggregateException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.SaveAzureVhdCommand
```

Answer (score 3):

Reason turns out to be undocumented, but quite common sense I suppose..

To copy the VHD to another storage account or to download it locally you can use powershell but the VM must be in Stopped state.
Because while the VM is running it is constantly writing into the VHD which modifies the file size and etag, causing a parallel copy to fail.